# Hibernate extracts funny falues from sequence

Tags: java, hibernate, sequence

We have defined a Hibernate entity, where the ID is numerical and automatically assigned by Hibernate based on a sequence. For technical reasons we do not allow our datamodel to be generated by hibernate but instead use liquibase to initiate the sequence.

We have seen strange behavior, where hibernate reassigns IDs already present in the table and also assigns negative values as IDs.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate (at least in 5.3.7) assumes a step of 50 when using sequences. This assumption is not checked against the database. Basically hibernate fetches the next value from the sequence and deducts 50, then assigning those values (X-49, X-48, ...). If your sequence has a step smaller than 50, you will see IDs being assigned multiple times. If your step is larger than 50, you will see non-continous IDs.

When you initialized the sequence by hand, you most probably had a step of 1. This means, you will see every ID being assigned 50 times and most probably you will see a lot of duplicate-key errors.

Either you set the step within your sequence to 50 or you use the `@SequenceGenerator` annotation and use the `allocationSize` attribute to match the step of your self-defined sequence.

Comment: is this meant as an answer, or as clarification on the question?

Comment: It is the answer to the question